# Test if a block is passed with RSpec Mocks

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I can test if arguments are passed like:

```
RSpec.describe do
  it do
    obj = double
    expect(obj).to receive(:method).with(1, 2, 3)
    obj.method(1, 2, 3)
  end
end
```

How should I do about a block parameter?  My ideal code:

```
RSpec.describe do
  it do
    obj = double
    proc = Proc.new{}
    expect(obj).to receive(:method).with(1, 2, 3).with_block(proc)
    obj.method(1, 2, 3, &proc)
  end
end
```

Comment: Requested this feature on Rspec issues https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1182

Answer (score 13):

It seems that I cannot simply test if a block is passed with method chaining. And I found one dull answer, Block Implementation:

```
RSpec.describe do
  it do
    obj = double
    proc = Proc.new{}
    expect(obj).to receive(:method).with(1, 2, 3) do |*args, &block|
      expect(proc).to be(block)
    end
    obj.method(1, 2, 3, &proc)
  end
end
```

However, we cannot use a block implementation and other response configuration methods at the same time like `receive(:method).with(1, 2, 3){|*| ...}.and_call_original`.

Comment: I wonder if you might be able to simulate `.and_call_original` by using `super(*args, &block)` in the block implementation....

Comment: RSpec should return the last statement in the do block:

Answer (score 3):

Based on the git ticket above, you can do this via

```
expect(object)
  .to receive(:method)
  .with(param1, param2) do |&block|
    expect(block).to be('my block contents')
  end
  .and_call_original
```

Which will validate the parameters are passed and evaluate the block contents.  You can then chain `.and_mock_original` or `.and_call_original` etc. afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use expectation to test that a specific block is passed. You can check that a code is run by adding code inside it, for example:

```
RSpec.describe do
  it do
    obj = double
    block_is = double('block')
    block = -> {
      block_is.run
    }

    expect(obj).to receive(:method).with(1, 2, 3).and_yield
    expect(block_is).to receive(:run)

    obj.method(1, 2, 3, &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, I just have been able to use: `allow(obj).to receive(:method).with(1, 2, 3, &a_proc).and_return(a_value)`. And it worked as expected.. EDIT: meh, rspec just ignored block )